# Corrupted FAT32 reinterpret file as folder

Tags: filesystems, file-recovery, fat32, filesystem-corruption

I am trying to recover data from a corrupted FAT32 filesystem. It was so severely damaged that it reinterpreted some files as folder contents. For instance, instead of a file names "FILE.DOC", it sees a folder named "FILE.DOC" containing lot of junk files whose names are parts of the original file.
Is there a way (even a complex one) to correct the FAT32 file to correct this one ?

Comment: Very doubtful, what caused the corruption?

Comment: Well, the difference between a FAT entry describing a file and one describing a directory is just one bit... only I can't think of any tools for easily changing it.

Comment: @user1686 Would you have more details on the precise structure ?

Comment: @Moab I don't know the details since it's the USB flash drive of a friend, but looks like an hardware failure.

Comment: @f4inx: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#Directory_table – "File Attributes"

Comment: Since it is a flash drive chances of recovery went down to 0

Comment: I eventually managed to recover these files by using Photorec. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is way too complicated to try and make sense of these files.

My suggestion is first to absolutely not change anything on the disk.
Secondly, try other data recovering utilities.

See the article
[Best Free Data Recovery and File Un-delete Utility](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm)
for a list of such products with reviews.

The number one utility, MiniTool Power Data Recovery, was also the best in my own
experience.

Comment: I eventually managed to recover these files by using Photorec. Thanks for your help.